# Magento 2 - Cart rule not working automatically

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

we have Magento 2.1.16 ce

I have made a shopping cart rule like this:

Percent of product price discount
Priority 0

Conditions:
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:
   If ANY of these conditions are 2:
      Collection is Autumn
      Collection is Winter

Actions:
Cart Items
Discount Amount 50.0000% of product
If ANY of these conditions are TRUE:
      Collection is Autumn
      Collection is Winter

When I add 2 items which match these conditions to the cart, it doe snot give the discount.
But when I click on update cart .... the discount will be applied.

Does anyone know why this is not being done automatically.

Because we want an other rule too.
With 3 or more items and than 60% discount.

But when I enable that rule, then 60% is also applied with 2 items in the cart ....

Comment: its magento2 defult behavior, you need to customize

Comment: Do you know what to do to make this work?